# React test cases failing using command npm test, please advise the failing reason

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

[Project Github link](https://github.com/AlcoholAllergy/TEST_FOR_SHOWCASE.git)

Hi!

Can anyone to check why I am having the following error when I was doing the test check by using command npm test.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')

      37 |     fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
      38 |     console.log('input successed!');
    > 39 |     expect(list.children[0].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('adam');
         |                             ^
      40 | 
      41 |     fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Dhilip' } });
      42 |     fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
```

It seems that the 1st child of the residentsNamelist is undefined.
However, I tried all functions in the web page by human input, all functions are just impletmented fine. I really need the reason of machine test failing.

The following is the test cases snippet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import App from './App';

const TEST_IDS = {
  nameInputId: 'studentName',
  joiningDateId: 'joiningDate',
  addBtnId: 'addBtn',
  errorMsgId: 'errorMsg',
  residentsNameList: 'residentsNameList',
};

describe('Hacker Dormitory', () => {
  let getByTestId;
  let txtInput;
  let dateInput;
  let addButton;
  let list;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const app = render(<App />);
    getByTestId = app.getByTestId;
    txtInput = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.nameInputId);
    dateInput = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.joiningDateId);
    addButton = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.addBtnId);
    list = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.residentsNameList);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it('should add valid students in Residents list', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Adam' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    console.log('input successed!');
    expect(list.children[0].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('adam');

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Dhilip' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    expect(list.children[0].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('adam');
    expect(list.children[1].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('dhilip');
  });

  it('should add valid students without case sensitivity', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'aDaM' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    expect(list.children[0].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('adam');
  });

  it('should clear the input fields after adding a new student', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Adam' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    expect(txtInput.value).toEqual('');
    expect(dateInput.value).toEqual('');
  });

  it('should show error on trying to add a student who is not in the list', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Anderson' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    let error = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.errorMsgId);
    expect(error.textContent).toEqual(
      'Sorry, Anderson is not a verified student!'
    );

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'dam' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2019-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    error = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.errorMsgId);
    expect(error.textContent).toEqual(`Sorry, dam is not a verified student!`);
  });

  it('should show error on trying to add a student whose validity has expired', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Bonnie' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2019-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });
    const error = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.errorMsgId);
    expect(error.textContent).toEqual(`Sorry, Bonnie's validity has Expired!`);
  });

  it('should hold the correct list and error message after series of Students addition', () => {
    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Adam' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Dhilip' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2020-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Talisk' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2023-12-11' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    let error = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.errorMsgId);
    expect(error.textContent).toEqual(`Sorry, Talisk's validity has Expired!`);

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Talisk' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2023-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    fireEvent.change(txtInput, { target: { value: 'Rock' } });
    fireEvent.change(dateInput, { target: { value: '2030-10-10' } });
    fireEvent.click(addButton, { button: '0' });

    error = getByTestId(TEST_IDS.errorMsgId);
    expect(error.textContent).toEqual(`Sorry, Rock is not a verified student!`);

    expect(list.children[0].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('adam');
    expect(list.children[1].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('dhilip');
    expect(list.children[2].textContent.toLowerCase()).toEqual('talisk');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please share your test file snippet, thanks!

Comment: What is this list? Likely, you will have to wait for some state to update while testing. Remember, when you check things by hand, your doing it really slowly allowing updates to propagate but while testing, every statement is executing at the speed of light (almost).

Comment: I added the test cases snippet!